# can ipad access bootmetro styles

Tags: ipad, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i am desiging a responsive website. i used bootmetro styles in my website. everything is working fine in samsung gelaxy tabs and other android devices. The problem is with Ipad.

i installed firebug in my ipad and tested all styles. The problem is, there are no bootmetro styles loaded in ipad.

So, my questions is can ipad access bootmetro styles? i saw a note in the firebug(in ipad) saying

**The results here may be inaccurate because some stylesheets could not be loaded due to access restrictions**

please help